# Safely removed external USB 3.0 disk reconnects on its own in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, docking-station

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and I have an external USB 3.0 docking station. The docking station is made by Plugable and it has an ASMedia chipset (http://plugable.com/products/usb3-sata-u3).

In Ubuntu, when I want to remove a disk that I've connected via the docking station, I right click the disk and select "Safely Remove". The disk temporarily disappears from Ubuntu and I can hear it spin down in the docking station. However, after about three seconds I hear the disk spin back up and it reappears in Ubuntu (it reconnects). I end up having to simply power off the docking station without safely removing the disk from Ubuntu, which I would prefer not to do. I've tried different disks of various sizes from 3TB to 250GB but the result is the same. I've also tried a second docking station of the same model but the result is also the same. I have an external hard drive from Iomega that does not have this problem. However, the Iomega external hard drive is USB 2.0.

Has anyone encountered this type of problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of people experience the same problem and for most people the behaviour is not consistent but seems to depend on the state of the OS.

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/792085

Still not solved, buying another type of disk may or may not help.

Workaround:
Just unmount the drive and then unplug it, when unmounting the drive it will be synced before unmounting so it is safe to remove after that. Just don't use "safely remove" at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

The docking station is broken; get a different model.